# email script PHP

Tags: php, html

I found an email script online to update my old one. Well, at the end of the day, everything works well, but the process form won't seem to send the email. Any clue what's wrong here?

```
<?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "byonexmusic" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "byonexmusic@gmail.com" );
define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "Visitor Message" );

// Read the form values
$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['senderName'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderName'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['senderEmail'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderEmail'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $message ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
  $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
}

// Return an appropriate response to the browser
if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
  echo $success ? "success" : "error";
} else {
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thanks!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ( $success ) echo "<p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>" ?>
  <?php if ( !$success ) echo "<p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>" ?>
  <p>Click your browser's Back button to return to the page.</p>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

And in case you're interested, here's the HTML form:

```
    <form id="contactForm" action="processForm.php" method="post">

  <h2>Send me an email...</h2>

  <ul>

    <li>
      <label for="senderName" class="laybel">Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Please type your name" required maxlength="40" / class="inputs">
    </li>

    <li>
      <label for="senderEmail" class="laybel">Your Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please type your email address" required maxlength="50" / class="inputs">
    </li>

    <li>
      <label for="message" style="padding-top: .5em;" class="laybel">Your Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Please type your message" required cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="10000" class="textareas"></textarea>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <div id="formButtons">
    <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Send Email" / class="button" style="color: #333">
    <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" / class="cancel button">
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: "won't seem to send the email" You have some code in there to report "success" or "error" - what does it do?? Do you get any error messages? Are you able to send email from the server by other methods?

Comment: You are never checking the value of $success. So if your $_GET["ajax"] value is supposed to be set through using the $success variable, no wonder it always says error.

Comment: I get no errors and the form closes. You can see it at http://byonex.Co.uk

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://byonex.co.uk/processForm.php?ajax=true

Comment: That's odd, I'm not getting any errors at all

Comment: Like I said, you aren't using anything to check $success with, you are also not setting this $_GET["ajax"] anywhere as well.

Answer (score 0):

The processForm.php page isn't loading. If you check your javascript console you'll see the following:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://byonex.co.uk/processForm.php?ajax=true`

I'd suggest trying that url in a seperate window until you get it working properly, then get the ajax stuff to work.

Edit: My gut feeling is that your url rewriting might be interfering with loading files ending in .php - actually it looks like any unknown url throws that error, for example: http://byonex.co.uk/thisshouldreturn404

Comment: Aha, you might be right! I'm going to check shortly.

Comment: Hmm, after removing everything from my .htaccess file (only about 6 lines) I'm just getting a 404 error. The weird thing is, I've tripled checked the file name is correct and in the same document.

Comment: That does sound weird. Check capitalization issues and try making a new test file and see if that works any better. Failing that you might need to open another question since that deals more with apache than the code you mentioned here.

Comment: So I fixed it.


The process form was in the wrong location.

OH my God.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept my answer if I helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this form.js

```
var messageDelay = 3000;  // How long to display status messages (in milliseconds)

// Init the form once the document is ready
$( init );


// Initialize the form

function init() {

  // Hide the form initially.
  // Make submitForm() the form's submit handler.
  // Position the form so it sits in the centre of the browser window.
  $('#contactForm').hide().submit( submitForm ).addClass( 'positioned' );

  // When the "Send us an email" link is clicked:
  // 1. Fade the content out
  // 2. Display the form
  // 3. Move focus to the first field
  // 4. Prevent the link being followed

  $('a[href="#contactForm"]').click( function() {
    $('#content').fadeTo( 'slow', .2 );
    $('#contactForm').fadeIn( 'slow', function() {
      $('#senderName').focus();
    } )

    return false;
  } );

  // When the "Cancel" button is clicked, close the form
  $('#cancel').click( function() { 
    $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
    $('#content').fadeTo( 'slow', 1 );
  } );  

  // When the "Escape" key is pressed, close the form
  $('#contactForm').keydown( function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 27 ) {
      $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
      $('#content').fadeTo( 'slow', 1 );
    }
  } );

}


// Submit the form via Ajax

function submitForm() {
  var contactForm = $(this);

  // Are all the fields filled in?

  if ( !$('#senderName').val() || !$('#senderEmail').val() || !$('#message').val() ) {

    // No; display a warning message and return to the form
    $('#incompleteMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
    contactForm.fadeOut().delay(messageDelay).fadeIn();

  } else {

    // Yes; submit the form to the PHP script via Ajax

    $('#sendingMessage').fadeIn();
    contactForm.fadeOut();

    $.ajax( {
      url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
      type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
      data: contactForm.serialize(),
      success: submitFinished
    } );
  }

  // Prevent the default form submission occurring
  return false;
}


// Handle the Ajax response

function submitFinished( response ) {
  response = $.trim( response );
  $('#sendingMessage').fadeOut();

  if ( response == "success" ) {

    // Form submitted successfully:
    // 1. Display the success message
    // 2. Clear the form fields
    // 3. Fade the content back in

    $('#successMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
    $('#senderName').val( "" );
    $('#senderEmail').val( "" );
    $('#message').val( "" );

    $('#content').delay(messageDelay+500).fadeTo( 'slow', 1 );

  } else {

    // Form submission failed: Display the failure message,
    // then redisplay the form
    $('#failureMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
    $('#contactForm').delay(messageDelay+500).fadeIn();
  }
}
```